# Can a contract be inherited?

Tags: solidity, inheritance

Just a random thought and a question. Can a smart contract written in solidity be inherited and if so, How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.  Just like this:

```solidity
contract Foo {
  ...
}

// Contract Bar inherits contract Foo
contract Bar is Foo {
  ...
}
```

Actually, one contract may inherit several contracts:

```
contract Foo {
  ...
}

contract Bar {
  ...
}

// Contract Zoo inherits contracts Foo and Bar
contract Zoo is Foo, Bar {
  ...
}
```

See [documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.12/contracts.html#inheritance) for details.

Comment: Okay, this is fine but what if one of my contract is already deployed on a network and now I am writing another contract and I want to inherit that contract. Is that possible?

Comment: Sure, in case you have source code of the first contract, just import it and inherit from it.  Your question is similar to the following C++/Java question: “May I inherit from a class, if I already created an instance of that class?”.  Surely you can.